# Solution to trigger event between container and element?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have a class like this:

```
public class Graph {
    Map<NodeKey,Node> nodes;

    List<RelationKey,Relation> relations;

    public void addNode(Node node){
        nodes.put(node.key,node);
    }

    public void addRelation(Relation relationship){
        relations.add(relation.key,relation);
    }

//getter and setter
}
public class Node {
    Map<RelationKey,Relation> relations;

    public void addRelationship(Relation relation){
        relations.put(relation.key,relation);
    }
//getter and setter
}
```

How can Graph call it's method: addRelation(Relation relationship) when node.addRelationship(Relation relation) is called. I can add Graph property in class Node but it seem not close to HAS-A relationships in OOP

Comment: Graph object already knows about its nodes relations, what is the purpose of Graph relations attributes?

Comment: @Francesco: You're right. But for high performance when find a relation to modify or when generate JSON to use in visualizing and for arrangement requirement (like minimum cross line).

Comment: @Francesco: Besides, when new relation is added to a node, new node should be add to graph.

Comment: Observer pattern is one of solutions

Comment: @Jerry06: I don't see the way observer pattern solve this problem. Could you write the example code?

Comment: Could a Graph object exists with its own relations but no nodes?

Comment: @Francesco: No, it can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Observer pattern like this:

```
class Node extends Observable {

    public Node(Observer observer){
        addObserver(observer);
    }

    public void addRelationship(Relation relation){
        relations.put(relation.key,relation);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(relation);
    }
}


class Graph implements Observer {
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        Relation relation = (Observable)arg;
        relations.add(relation.key,relation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it that way, you can use the observer pattern ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern ). Then, your `Graph` class (the observer) can be notified about relations added to its constituent nodes (the subjects).

That said, I advise you to change your design. Usually, graphs are not designed with a single class that holds all the graph data. Once you fix the 'add' issue, you will face the same issue to remove a node. And what about moving a whole part of your graph from one node to another ? Maintaining duplicate information (because that's what you are doing : the node class holds everything you need) is really a pain.

You should probably go for an abstract algebraic data type ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type ) with two children concrete classes `Node` and `Leaf`. Then you can explore your graph to do anything you need. Look at trees, which are a particular kind of graphs that are really well documented. And indeed, they are referenced as an example in the link I just provided herebefore.

Comment: Thank for your advise. I'll try to change my design